# Getting DAG import errors in Apache Airflow metrics but no such error is visible on UI

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I am using AWS MWAA (Managed Workflow for Apache Airflow) and setting up monitoring for the same.

Airflow Version: v2.2.2
Metric: dag_processing.import_errors

My airflow setup is being used by multiple teams to execute their DAGs and so I wanted to ensure that there are no breaking changes pushed to Airflow. This is the reason that I have setup an alert on the metric.

The metric gives me import errors intermittently (2-3 times a day). At that particular time there is no import error available on the UI nor any errors in dag_processing logs. The DAG themselves are running fine without any issue/s. I raised AWS support for the same and did not get anything fruitful as they said that they have no control on the metrics that are being emitted from the open source Airflow.

Any suggestions on why this could happen or even what steps could be done to debug it further would be really helpful. Without any error/s, I am essentially stuck.